# How to manage onTouchListener Return value from ACTION_MOVE event, like i want to change(true or false) return value while ACTION_MOVE event called

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

I want create CardStackView with scrolling content but getting some issue with NestedScrollView and onTouchListener.

I'm using CardStackView and i want to add scrolling content inside cardview. after adding NestedScrollView inside row XML file my Swipe not working.

```
holder.textViewCheck.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener())
```

in this below code i'm disable scrolling while detect swipe left and right in TouchListener but at a time only one function is working.

```
private var xDelta: Int = 0
    private var yDelta: Int = 0
    private fun onTouchListener(): OnTouchListener {
        return OnTouchListener { view, event ->
            val x = event.x.toInt()
            val y = event.y.toInt()
            val tAG = "AppName"

            when (event.actionMasked) {

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.None)

                    xDelta = x
                    yDelta = y

                    true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.AutomaticAndManual)
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "thanks for new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    false
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    val finalX = event.x
                    val finalY = event.y

//                    Log.e(tAG, "xDelta $xDelta ---------- FinalX $finalX ---------- Final+X ${xDelta + 100}")
//                    Log.e(tAG, "xDelta $xDelta ---------- FinalX $finalX ---------- Final-X ${xDelta - 100}")

                    when {
                        finalX > xDelta + 100 -> {
                            view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                            cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.AutomaticAndManual)
//                            Log.e(tAG, "Left to Right swipe performed")

                            true
                        }

                        finalX < xDelta - 100 -> {
                            view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                            cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.AutomaticAndManual)
//                            Log.e(tAG, "Right to Left swipe performed")

                            true
                        }

                        yDelta < finalY -> {
                            view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                            cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.None)
//                            Log.e(tAG, "Up to Down swipe performed")

                            false
                        }

                        yDelta > finalY -> {
                            view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                            cardStackManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.None)
//                            Log.e(tAG, "Down to Up swipe performed")
                            false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

Below link is for CardStakeView library for check and understand my issue easily.

i'm customise this library

https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by _at a time only one function is working._

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to achieve independent scrolling action right? https://github.com/TakuCoder/MultiScrollView.git follow my github repo